# Maven: Source Not Specified... But why?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

Okay, so this is my first Maven project. This is the last thing I need to complete, but it keeps pointing me back to this.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: source not specified
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST (ASTParser.java:830)
    at com.javaAST.ASTParse.parse (ASTParse.java:25)
    at com.javaAST.Main.main (Main.java:59)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:830)
```

Ultimately, it is from this page

```
package com.javaAST;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleName;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationFragment;

public class ASTParse
{
    public static FileList fileList = new FileList();
    public static ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);

    public static void parse(List<String> results) throws IOException
    {

        final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

        for (String result : results)
        {
            //Create output file
            String addExtension = result.toLowerCase() + ".ast";
            System.out.println("Creating File: " + addExtension);
            File output = new File(addExtension);
            output.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output);


            //Begin ASTParser
            parser.setSource(result.toCharArray());
            parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

            cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

                Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();

                public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {
                    SimpleName name = node.getName();
                    this.names.add(name.getIdentifier());
                    try
                    {
                        fw.write("Declaration of '" + name + "' at line" + cu.getLineNumber(name.getStartPosition()) + "\n");
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return false; // do not continue to avoid usage info
                }

                public boolean visit(SimpleName node) {
                    if (this.names.contains(node.getIdentifier())) {
                        try
                        {
                            fw.write("Usage of '" + node + "' at line " + cu.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition()) + "\n");
                        } catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and the `pom.xml` does contain

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

, but I keep getting this error. Now the `.jar` is creating this file, `ASTParser.class` and `ASTParser$1.class` which I don't fully understand yet, but I don't think that's enough to break it. Any guidance from someone with some experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your maven setup. There is a mistake in how your code uses the AST parser. You're getting an `IllegalStateException` on line 25:

```
final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

According to the [API specs for the Eclipse AST parser](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTParser.html), this exception is thrown on `createAST` when:

> IllegalStateException - if the settings provided are insufficient, contradictory, or otherwise unsupported

A further clue is in the exception message: 'source not specified'. You need to set a source, presumably by using `parser.setSource()`, *before* calling `createAST`.

Comment: Why did I have that at first, though!!! Many thanks. It makes perfect sense now...